# My rowcommand has no command name for my gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have an image button that is created on rowcreated manually in code.

```
Dim deletecshr As New ImageButton
    deletecshr.ImageUrl = "\images\bttnDeletemini.gif"
    deletecshr.ToolTip = "This Will Delete All Cashiers"
    deletecshr.ID = "deletecshr"
```

In gridveiw_rowdatabound I have the following:

```
Dim deletecshr As ImageButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("deletecshr"), ImageButton)
            deletecshr.CommandName = "Delete"
            deletecshr.CommandArgument = emp_no & "," & e.Row.Cells(2).Text & "," & e.Row.Cells(1).Text & "," & cashier_no & "," & manager_no
```

I set the commandname and the argument.

However, in rowcommand it finds no commandname or anything else. What am i doing wrong? I believe this has worked before.

Comment: Did you remember to attach the RowCommand event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i can tell you never attach the event.

```
Dim deletecshr As New ImageButton
deletecshr.ImageUrl = "\images\bttnDeletemini.gif"
deletecshr.ToolTip = "This Will Delete All Cashiers"
deletecshr.ID = "deletecshr"
AddHandler deletecshr.Command AddressOf deletecshrCommandEventHandler
```

You'll have a method similar of this in your code:

```
Protected Sub deletecshrCommandEventHandler(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
  If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then

    'Do your stuff

  End IF
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Added some more code and fixed a small syntax error.

Comment: This didn't work. there is no .RowCommand being that it is an image button.

Comment: Thank you! I eventually got it to work using your idea. thanks